# Managing font installation/removal on Windows using python

Tags: python, windows, fonts

After some researching I found out that I can install a truetype font for the current user by just making a new string value in `HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Fonts` with NAME set to the font's name and DATA set to the font's path. Removing a font is also similar, first you remove the string value for the specified font and then delete the font file itself.

I tried to do it manually and it does work (both installing and removing a font). But recreating everything in python lands me into a problem. I'm able to install font using the above method but when I try to remove the font then windows tells me that [the font file is currently being used by "System"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jD5e3.png). My program is able to remove the registry value but fails to delete the font file.

My helper registry editor functions can be found at -> https://github.com/nk521/phonts/blob/07a4d6de5165d5c19861c2f28708c60d52f33df9/core/helpers/win.py

This function installs a font -> https://github.com/nk521/phonts/blob/07a4d6de5165d5c19861c2f28708c60d52f33df9/core/win.py#L15

This function deletes a font -> https://github.com/nk521/phonts/blob/07a4d6de5165d5c19861c2f28708c60d52f33df9/core/win.py#L35

This line will generate a `PermissionError` -> https://github.com/nk521/phonts/blob/07a4d6de5165d5c19861c2f28708c60d52f33df9/core/win.py#L41

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On Windows, GDI may lock font files that have been used. You might not be able to delete the font file until that user session has ended. If you delete the registry entry, then the font won't get loaded into GDI in the next session. Try deleting the reg entry, then log off and back on, that might unlock the file; or if it has locked it in a different session, you might need to reboot.

Comment: Peter, yes you're correct. I'm able to delete them after a restart/logout. Thank you very much :)